# Pandas - dataframe containing comments(rows) and words as column headers how to get a frequency count?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp, nltk

I am trying to perform a word frequency count on a relatively large dataframe and don't know what approach would be the best.

Currently my dataframe looks like this -

```
 Comment        'I'    'it'    'is'    'up'

'I was here'    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
'I like soup'   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
'whats up'      NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
'This is it'    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

My goal is to perform a frequency count for each of the words in the column headers ('I', 'it', 'is', 'up') for each comment. E.g. after the counting process the result should look something like this -

```
 Comment        'I'    'it'    'is'    'up'

'I was here'     1      0        0      0
'I like soup'    1      0        0      0
'whats up'       0      0        0      1
'This is it'     0      1        1      0
```

What would be the best approach to this? The real dataset contains about 50k comments and over 10k columns with different words.

Comment: Is this the best design for your table? Apparently you will have a _really_ sparse data frame if you put single words as columns. This means a BIG part of your data frame will just have zeros and its dimensions would scale greatly. What are you trying to achieve at the end? Just the could of each word in a text? There are many other ways to do that, and maybe a pandas dtaframe is not the best design for this ;)

Comment: Thank you for your input! I am trying to generate a dataset that later would be suitable for ml. Each column(word) will stand as a feature and I will be looking to find which words are the most influential for my target

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is a better way than:

```
for column in df.columns[1:]: # All but comment column.
   df[column] = df[column].str.contains(df['Comment'])
```

This will give you a matrix of booleans, which you can map to bits if you really need.

Comment: This fails to take multiple occurrences of the same word into account.

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions `Counter()` and `itemgetter()`:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

iget = itemgetter(*df.columns[1:])
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df['Comment'].str.split().\
apply(lambda x: pd.Series(iget(Counter(x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is using a for loop:

```
for target in df.columns:
    for sentence in df.index:
        n = 0
        for word in sentence.split(' '):
            print(word)
            if word == target:
                n += 1
        df.loc[sentence, target] = n
```

However, I agree with @rafaelc and have my doubts towards the design of your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.findall` with `Counter` if you need regex:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({"Comment":['I was here I','I like soup','whats up','This is it'],})

comments = ['I','it','is','up']

s = df["Comment"].str.findall("|".join(fr"\b{i}\b" for i in comments)).apply(Counter)

print (pd.concat([df, s.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1))

#
        Comment    I   up   is   it
0  I was here I  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   I like soup  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2      whats up  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
3    This is it  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please explain what does fr"\b{i}\b" do?

Comment: It is a word boundary which matches the empty string at the beginning and end of a word, thus preventing matching like `it` from `digit`. Read [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for details.

Comment: very interesting thanks for your reply. For some reason its filtering out ~50% of my column names, I will try to figure out why